# How can I read the SSL certificate with Selenium Wire?

Tags: selenium

The question is simple as the title: How can I read SSL certificates with Selenium Wire?

All Google results were about SSL certificate errors.

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver  # Import from seleniumwire

# Create a new instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Go to the Google home page
driver.get('https://www.google.com')

# Access requests via the `requests` attribute
for request in driver.requests:
    if request.response:
        print(
            # SSL certificate
        )
```

How does this work for Firefox?

Comment: Your code trials?

Comment: Added a code block where I would like to show the content of an SSL certificate

Comment: Interesting question! I never tried to do this, but you might be able to do something with CDP: https://applitools.com/blog/selenium-4-chrome-devtools/